# I have made my own collision checker system for a demo but my collisions are not interacting properly

Tags: c, collision-detection, collision

So I have made a simple demo for rect collision checking but when it comes to stopping the objects from going through each other, my code leaves a small gap between the two objects for no apparent reason even though there should be no space left when the objects collide. I do not fully know why this happens yet but I know the bug is in the `checkCollisionRect()` function as it is the one that is in charge of handling the behaviour of the rects.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define or ||
#define and &&
#define pCharacter "%c \n"
#define pInteger "%d \n"
#define pFloat "%f \n"
#define pDouble "%lf \n"
#define pUnsighned "%u \n"
#define pString "%s \n"

/*
format string:| input type:
      %c      | character
      %d      | digit (integer)
      %f      | float
      %lf     | double
      %u      | unsigned
      %s      | string
*/

int width=1000; //Screen width
int height=500; //Screen height
int px=200; //Player pos x
int py=100; //Player pos y
float playerSpeed=5.0;

void drawRect(int tlx,int tly,int boxWidth,int boxHeight){
 glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
 glVertex2f(tlx,tly+boxHeight); //Bottom Left
 glVertex2f(tlx,tly); //Top Left
 glVertex2f(tlx+boxWidth,tly); //Top Right
 glVertex2f(tlx+boxWidth,tly+boxHeight); //Bottom Right
 glEnd();
}

void checkCollisionRect(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2){
 if(x1>x2+w2 or x1+w1<x2 or y1>y2+h2 or y1+h1<y2){
  glColor3f(0,1,0);
 }
 else{
  glColor3f(1,0,0);
  if(x1<x2+w2 and x1+w1>x2 and y1<y2+h2){
   py-=playerSpeed;
   printf("top\n");
  }
  if(y1+h1>y2 and y1<y2+h2 and x1<x2+w2){
   px-=playerSpeed;
   printf("left\n");
  }
  if(x1<x2+w2 and x1+w1>x2 and y1+h1>y2){
   py+=playerSpeed;
   printf("bottom\n");
  }
  if(y1+h1>y2 and y1<y2+h2 and x1+w1>x2){
   px+=playerSpeed;
   printf("right\n");
  }
 }
}
    
void drawSquare(px,py,size){
 glPointSize(size);
 glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 glVertex2i(px,py);
 glEnd();
}

void Buttons(unsigned char key,int x,int y){
 if(key=='a'){px-=playerSpeed;}     
 if(key=='d'){px+=playerSpeed;} 
 if(key=='w'){py-=playerSpeed;}
 if(key=='s'){py+=playerSpeed;}
}               
 
void display(){
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 //-----------------------Draw----------------------
 checkCollisionRect(px,py,10,10,200,200,100,100);
 drawRect(200,200,100,100); //rect
 drawRect(px,py,10,10); //player
 //-------------------------------------------------
 glutSwapBuffers();
 glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init(){
 glClearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3,0);
 gluOrtho2D(0,width,height,0);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv){ 
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
 glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
 init();
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutKeyboardFunc(Buttons);
 glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: why would you re-define || and && as macros?

Comment: Because I use a Spanish keyboard and us such there is no key that allows me to use the vertical bar, also I just find more comfort in having them as macros as I personally it more accessible and easier to use in my case.

Comment: I suspect `if(x1>x2+w2 or x1+w1<x2 or y1>y2+h2 or y1+h1<y2)` should use `and`.

Comment: Aside, rather than `#define or || #define and &&`, research `<iso646.h>`.

Comment: I assume that the square is immovable and collisions therefrom are perfectly elastic. Therefore, to properly do a collision, you have to detect the collision in time and then reflect the position and update the velocity. Concave surfaces are tricky on the edge. Suggest that you may want to work on an infinite plane first, (like Pong.)

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica I fixed it, I am not sure the comments are correct ether since some times the behaviour is just weird and its hard to know what is what. Also, using and or or is irrelevant since you are able to do it both ways

Comment: @BOOTRE: defining macros is not a good fix for your keyboard ailments. If you are using a Mac, you can type `|` and `&` using alt key combinations and on Windows, you can use AtlGr key combinations. Using these macros makes the code difficult to read and error prone.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the infromation but I am using a Spanish specific keyboard, there is no combination of keys that allows me to make | even if I wanted to.

Comment: @BOOTRE: it is not really keyboard specific, more OS specific. What is your platform?

Comment: Please look at the layout of the keyboard in this webpage: https://spanish.yourdictionary.com/spanish-language/learning-spanish/spanish-keyboard-and-punctuation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the final solution, there  is still a small gap but there is nothing I can do about it, basically once you collide with the other rect you will enter a loop where the game will check if you are in the rect and push you back by one pixel, it will do this continuously.

```html
void checkCollisionRect(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
    if(x1>x2+w2 or x1+w1<x2 or y1>y2+h2 or y1+h1<y2)
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    else {
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        if (x1 < x2) {       // player hit the left wall
            printf("Left\n");
            px -= 1;
        }
        if (x1+w1 > x2+w2) { // player hit the right wall
            printf("Right\n");
            px += 1;
        }
        if (y1 < y2) {       // player hit the top wall
            printf("Top\n");
            py -= 1;
        }
        if (y1+h1 > y2+h2) { // player hit the bottom wall
            printf("Bottom\n");
            py += 1;
        }
    }
}
```